# if I have multiple Java flight recorder files (.JFR) , how do I merge them together to see them at Java mission control in one time

Tags: java, jfr

I received for analysis a bunch of multiple JFR files , like 170 , and it is taking too long to open one by one, can I  put them in one single file, starting from the fact that I only have the files and I cannot configure the JVM and obtain the JFR again.
for example

- 2020_03_30_20_37_01_2333_0.jfr
- 2020_03_30_21_37_01_2333_0.jfr
- 2020_03_30_22_37_01_2333_0.jfr
- 2020_03_30_23_37_01_2333_0.jfr

  .
  .
  .
- N

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the 'jfr' tool located in JDK_HOME/bin from 11.06 or later.

```
$ jfr assemble <repository> <file>
```

where **repository** is the directory where the files are located and **file** is the name of the recording file (.jfr) to create.

A recording file is just a concatenation of chunk files so you could do it in the shell as well. For example, using the copy /b command in Windows

```
 $ copy /b 1.jfr + 2.jfr + 3.jfr combined.jfr
```

Comment: this would just concatenate the results to a single file or even aggregate the results?

Comment: It will just concatenate the result into a single file. Any aggregation is handled by the GUI.

Comment: thank you. What do you mean with the gui? Is there some kind of function to aggregate reocrding files for the same class (for example)?

Comment: If you use JDK Mission Control, it can show aggregated statistics, for example method profiling aggregated per class or package.

Comment: on linux, you can use `cat jfr_file_version_* >> combined.jfr`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script in windows powershell to concatenate the JFR files, just take care of the size of the final concatenated file, it might be too large, in that case you might want to reduce the files to concatenate

```bsh
    $Location = ""
    $outputConcatenatedJFR = "all_2333_1.jfr"
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *2333_1.jfr | Sort-Object -Property Name
    New-Item $outputConcatenatedJFR -ItemType file
    ForEach ($item in $items) {
       Write-Host "Processing file - " $item
       cmd /c copy /b $outputConcatenatedJFR+$item $outputConcatenatedJFR
    }
```